# Getting access to Android sounds

Tags: android, audio

I was wondering if it was possible to get access to the Android's hangup call sound files. For example I want to be able to load whatever the hang up sound is for the phone and play that using the MediaPlayer.

Has anybody done something like this before?

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, the hangup sound is not stored in any sound file (I wasted a bunch of time searching). Instead, a [DTMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling) tone is generated. Here is how to generate the hang up sound:

```
    ToneGenerator toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, 80); //80 is volume
    toneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_PROMPT, 200); //200 is length
```

[You can view the original source in the built in phone app here.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.2_r1.1/com/android/phone/CallNotifier.java#1261)